# Azure: accessing the Management API using the oAuth key from the Enterprise account

Tags: api, azure, enterprise

I have an Enterprise account with a 'Usage Api Access Key'.
I can use this key to make calls to:

https://ea.azure.com/rest/{account-id}/usage-reports

by setting the Authorization header on my REST call.

Unfortunately I can't use these same keys to call the Usage Management API using the an address like the one below with the subscription Id substituted in:

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{suscription-id}/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&reportedStartTime=2015-02-01T09%3A00%3A00&reportedEndTime=2015-02-08T09%3A00%3A00&aggregationGranularity=Daily&showDetails=false

as the result is always: 
    {
      "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticationFailed",
        "message": "Authentication failed."
      }
    }

Do I have to create a different type of key for this API?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer, the steps listed out here worked for me:

http://www.bizbert.com/bizbert/2015/07/08/Setting+Up+PostMan+To+Call+The+Azure+Management+APIs.aspx